# Oracle Managed Data Provider does not parse the complete TNSNames entries

Tags: c#, oracle, tnsnames

I am trying to use the following code that I found in couple of places to read the TNSNames.ora file.

```
        OracleClientFactory factory = OracleClientFactory.Instance;

        if (factory.CanCreateDataSourceEnumerator)
        {

            OracleDataSourceEnumerator dsenum = factory.CreateDataSourceEnumerator() as OracleDataSourceEnumerator;

            DataTable dt = dsenum.GetDataSources();
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dt.Columns[0] + " : " + row[0]);
                Console.WriteLine(dt.Columns[1] + " : " + row[1]);
                Console.WriteLine(dt.Columns[2] + " : " + row[2]);
                Console.WriteLine(dt.Columns[3] + " : " + row[3]);
                Console.WriteLine(dt.Columns[4] + " : " + row[4]);
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------");

            }
        }
```

The TNSNames.Ora entry looks like this

```
PDB01= (DESCRIPTION_LIST= (LOAD_BALANCE=OFF)(FAILOVER=ON)
 (DESCRIPTION =  (CONNECT_TIMEOUT=3)(RETRY_COUNT=1)
  (ADDRESS_LIST =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = server1.domain.com)(PORT = 1648)))
            (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = PDB01_SRV)))
 (DESCRIPTION =    (CONNECT_TIMEOUT=3)(RETRY_COUNT=1)
   (ADDRESS_LIST =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = server2.domain.com)(PORT = 1648)))
             (CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = PDB01_SRV))))
```

However, I see that the `GetDataSources` method always returns only the first data source (server1.domain.com) and not the second one (server2.domain.com). Any idea why and how to get both? Does it not understand a "DESCRIPTION_LIST"?

Here is the output:

```
InstanceName : PDB_01
ServerName : server1.domain.com
ServiceName : PDB01_SRV
Protocol : TCP
Port : 1648
--------------------
```

Just one out of the two entries in the ORA file.

My intention is to parse the TNSNames.ora file and get to its content.

Comment: I think your tnsnames.ora is wrong. You set only one alias for two services, looks like you missed one line

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, I have now updated a more relevant TNSNames sample with the exact file I received from the Oracle team. Tested with TNSPing

Comment: What is the output you get from `Console.WriteLine(...)`?

Comment: Please edit your question instesd of putting additional information as comments.

Comment: Added output result as well, to the question

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.